# how to modify query string whose filter value contains &

Tags: xml, sharepoint, query-string

I have constructed an URL like -

```
http://server_name/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={List-Id}&XMLDATA=TRUE&View={View-Id}&Query=*&FilterField1=Country_x0020_Name&FilterValue1=UK & Ireland
```

which ofcourse doesnot give me the expected output. 
How to specify the filer value if there is an '&' character in the string?
The filter value is retrieved from a sharepoint list that contains the list of countries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode the value of the filter parameter according to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). If you're building the url using javascript, then you would do this using a call to `encodeURIComponent(rawData)`:

```
var url = hostpath + "?Query=" + encodeURIComponent(filterValue);
```

This will take care of '&', spaces and other characters that would otherwise cause a problem. If you're hard-coding the URL, then you can use one of the many public access tools to see what the encoded value should look like, e.g. [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp)